# Is there any other way to add sound in HTML webpages other than <audio>?

Tags: html

The <audio> tag is normally used for adding sound, but since I'm using a chromebook, I can't select a file for the src attribute, so I was wondering if there was any other way to add sound in HTML. If not, is there ANY way to add sound in any programming language that doesn't involve specifying the name of a stored file?

Comment: Feels like an XY problem to me. What’re you trying to do here: serving a local HTML file on a chrome book? What about hosting the audio file on a CDN or in the cloud?

Answer (score 0):

In the `src=""` attribute you can even put a link to an audio online. Try loading that audio from an online source.

Comment: I tried this, but the audio that pops up doesn't work, as if I entered an invalid source.

Comment: Then try this way:

mySound = new Audio('sound.mp3');
mySound.play()